# A question in inequalities involving modulus

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

How do I solve this sum:

> Solve for $x \in \mathbb {R} $
>
> $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$

Comment: Do you know triangle inequality? When does equality holds in triangle inequality?

Comment: do case work to eliminate the absolute value signs

Comment: When everything else fails you could divide it into cases according to the signs of $x^2-2x$, $x-4$ or $x^2-3x+4$, but first try Sayan's tip...

Comment: What's the triangle inequality @Sayan? Sum of two sides always greater than third side?

Comment: Did you look at the meaning of the tag (modular-arithmetic) before using it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the triangle inequality, you have $\forall \, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$$
where the *equality* only holds when $a$ and $b$ have the same sign (both positive or both negative) or when at least one of $a$ and $b$ is equal to $0$; this means:

- $|a+b| = |a| + |b| \iff ab \ge 0$;
- $|a+b| < |a| + |b| \iff ab < 0$.

---

Now notice that with $a=x^2-2x$ and $b=4-x$, you can rewrite:
$$\left| x^2-3x+4 \right|=\left| x^2-2x+ (4-x) \right| \le \left| x^2-2x \right|+\left|4-x\right|$$
So all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy "$\le$" and for your "$<$", you only need to find out where the *strict inequality* holds and from above, we know this happens when $a$ and $b$ are non-zero and have a different sign, i.e. when $ab < 0$; so that leaves you with solving:
$$\left( x^2-2x \right)\left(4-x\right) < 0 \iff x\left( x-2 \right)\left(4-x\right) < 0 \iff \ldots$$

Comment: Did you understand it in wording, just above? The fact that $a$ and $b$ have to have the same sign or at least one has to be zero, is equivalent to their product being non-negative, or symbolically: $ab \ge 0$. Similarly, having a _different sign_ **and** being _non-zero_, is equivalent to having a (strict) negative product, symbolically: $ab<0$.

Comment: I now understand. Does this yield the result  $x \in (0, 2) \cup (4, \infty) $? I'll try it in a while, as soon as I reach home, but it looks good.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks.

Comment: @WrichikBasu That's correct!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|x^2-3x+4|=x^2-3x+4$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ as $x^2-3x+4$ is always positive.

When $x\le 0$, $|x^2-2x|=x^2-2x$ and $|x-4|=4-x$. So

\begin{align*}
x^2-2x+4-x&>x^2-3x+4\\
\end{align*}

which is impossible.

When $0<x\le 2$, $|x^2-2x|=2x-x^2$ and $|x-4|=4-x$. So

\begin{align*}
2x-x^2+4-x&>x^2-3x+4\\
2x^2-4x&<0\\
0<x&<2
\end{align*}

The solution for this case is $0<x<2$.

When $x>2$,  $|x^2-2x|=x^2-2x$ and $|x-4|=x-4$. So

\begin{align*}
x^2-2x+x-4&>x^2-3x+4\\
2x&>8\\
x&>4
\end{align*}
The solution in this case is $x>4$.

The final answer is $0<x<2$ or $x>4$.

Alternatively, we have $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|=|x^2-2x|+|4-x|\ge|(x^2-2x)+(4-x)|=|x^2-3x+4|$ by triangle inequality, with the equality holds if and only if $x^2-2x$ and $x-4$ have the same sign, i.e. $x(x-2)(4-x)\ge0$.

So $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$ if and only if $x(x-2)(4-x)<0$, i.e. $0<x<2$ or $x>4$.

Comment: Too complicated.......

Comment: I posted two methods here. Sometimes we cannot solve the problem only by triangle inequality. That's why we need the first method.

Comment: Second one is better. @CY

Comment: At least for this particular problem

Answer (score 1):

Since for all reals $a$ and $b$ we have
$$|a|+|b|=|a|+|-b|\geq|a-b|$$
and $x^2-2x-(x-4)=x^2-3x+4>0$, we get the answer:
$\mathbb R\setminus$ $\{$cases of equality occuring$\}$

and since  for $x\in(-\infty,0]$ or for $x\in[2,4]$ we get equality,

we obtain
$$\mathbb R\setminus\left((-\infty,0]\cup[2,4]\right)=(0,2)\cup(4,+\infty)$$

Comment: Wrong answer, @Michael Rozenberg.

Comment: Wrichik Basu Why?

Comment: Ans given as $x \in (0, 2)\cup (4, \infty) $.

Comment: @Wrichik Basu Because for $x\in(-\infty,0]$ or for $x\in[2,4]$ we get equality.

Comment: @Rozenberg Got it. 